# Make a smaller Array out of an existing array JAVA

Tags: java

I want to return the length of the new list. I start by searching for matching values. I then find the difference. From that I pick the one with the largest difference and from that I want the length of the new array starting from the first instance of of the matching value to the last. Instead it comes up with an error. How do i fix this?

The error is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at workout.lis(workout.java:15)
at workout.main(workout.java:31)

```
public class workout {

    public static int lis(int[] A, int n){       
        int maxDifference = 0;
        int newList [] = new int[maxDifference];

        for (int i =0; i<n;i++){
            for( int j = 0; j<n; j++ ){
                if( A[i]== A[j]){
                    int difference = j-i;
                    if (difference > maxDifference){
                        maxDifference = difference;
                        for (int x = 0; x<maxDifference;x++){
                            newList[x] = A[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return newList.length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5 };
        int n = arr.length;
        System.out.println("Length of lis is "
                + lis( arr, n ) + "\n" );

    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "Instead it comes up with an error" What is the error?

Comment: It needs examples on input and expected output.

Comment: @AndyTurner Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
 at workout.lis(workout.java:15)
 at workout.main(workout.java:31)

Comment: `maxDifference = 0` + `new int[maxDifference]` = `new int[0]` --- `new int[0]` + `newList[x] = ...` = `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` --- What is surprising about that? Updating `maxDifference` does not re-allocate the array, and arrays are fixed-length, they don't auto-expand.

Comment: Which one is line 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public static int list(int[] arr) {
        // iterate over an array and save first occurence position from left and right for each key
        Map<Integer, Integer> offsLeft = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> offsRight = new HashMap<>();
        Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<>();

        for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < arr.length; i++, j--) {
            keys.add(arr[i]);
            offsLeft.putIfAbsent(arr[i], i);
            offsRight.putIfAbsent(arr[j], j);
        }

        // calculate max difference of all key
        int maxKey = arr[0];

        for (int key : keys) {
            int diff = offsRight.get(key) - offsLeft.get(key);
            int maxDiff = offsRight.get(maxKey) - offsLeft.get(maxKey);
            maxKey = diff > maxDiff ? key : maxKey;
        }

        // get left and right positions of the key
        int left = offsLeft.get(maxKey);
        int right = offsRight.get(maxKey);
        // right - left is your max difference
        // we also able to find the new array
        int[] res = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, left, right + 1);   // [2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2]
        return res.length;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5 };
        System.out.println("Length of lis is " + list(arr) + '\n');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) that stores the first seen index of a integers as you iterate over the array and [Arrays.**copyOfRange**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-) to simplify the logic a little:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5};
    int arrLength = arr.length;
    System.out.printf("arr=%s, arrLength=%d%n", Arrays.toString(arr), arrLength);
    int[] newArr = getSubArrayBetweenFurthestApartDuplicates(arr);
    System.out.printf("newArr=%s, newArrLength=%d%n", Arrays.toString(newArr), newArr.length);
  }

  private static int[] getSubArrayBetweenFurthestApartDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> firstSeenPosition = new HashMap<>();
    int maxDist = 0, subArrayStart = 0, subArrayEnd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      int x = arr[i];
      if (!firstSeenPosition.containsKey(x)) {
        firstSeenPosition.put(x, i);
      } else {
        int newDist = i - firstSeenPosition.get(x) + 1;
        if (newDist > maxDist) {
          maxDist = newDist;
          subArrayStart = firstSeenPosition.get(x);
          subArrayEnd = i;
        }
      }
    }
    if (subArrayStart == 0 && subArrayEnd == 0) {
      return new int[0];
    }
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, subArrayStart, subArrayEnd + 1);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5], arrLength=8
newArr=[2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2], newArrLength=6
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing **int newList [] = new int[maxDifference];** it is declaring the newList with 0 length since maxDifference is 0. And array doesn't re-allocate the memory again if we need more. That's why it is giving error. I would suggest you to implement collection (arrayList) here for newList not array